# How to delete search element in vim with * pattern

Tags: regex, vim

```
<div style=\"display:none\">some text</div>
<div style=\"display:none\">other text</div>
```

**How to remove all the div in a file, any position of any line**

I tried out somthing like below but don't work

```
:%s/\<div\ style\=\\\"display\:none\\\"\>*\<\/div\>//g
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
:%s/<div style=\\"display:none\\">.*<\/div>//g
```

Comment: Thanks ! actually I forgot the dot .